# How to communicate an event from one fragment to another?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The event in my case is a simple Button click. I've read [Communicate with other fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating), but that seems to be limited to data, not events.

I'm considering incrementing an Integer (or flipping a Boolean) and reacting to the LiveData observer, ignoring the actual value. Not sure if that would be considered Clean Code though...

Then there is the long way of communicating via interfaces; however, one of the fragments in question is added in xml, thus the Activity doesn't even know about it (and can't attach a listener to it).

Is there a clean way to communicate an event like a Button click from one Fragment to another?

Comment: Use a shared `ViewModel`, as that page recommends. [This sample Java app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v1.0/NukeFromOrbit) uses the single-live-event pattern, which is not ideal but does not require RxJava. [Its Kotlin counterpart](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v1.0/NukeFromOrbit) uses a `BroadcastChannel`, exposed via a `Flow`.

Comment: Those samples assume that you truly mean "events" (i.e., something to be processed exactly once and not to be retained across configuration changes). For stuff that should survive a configuration change, that is a state change, not an event, and `LiveData` or `StateFlow` are fine choices.